# return data from array of hash based on date range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following array of hash

```
[ { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, start_date: '2017-01-01', end_date: '2017-02-01'},
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 1, start_date: '2017-03-01', end_date: '2017-04-01'},
{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 3, start_date: '2017-05-01', end_date: '2017-06-01'},
{ a: 4, b: 4, c: 4, start_date: '2017-07-01', end_date: '2017-08-01'},
{ a: 4, b: 5, c: 5, start_date: '2017-09-01', end_date: '2017-12-01'} ]
```

I am trying to get the list of hash based start_date and end_date. I tried to achieve it like below but it returns `[]`

```
params[:start_date] = '2017-01-01'
params[:end_date] = '2017-06-01'

array.select {|e| e[:start_date] == params[:start_date] && e[:end_date] == params[:end_date] }
```

So based on the start_date and end_date inputs, it should return first 3 hash from array

```
{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, start_date: '2017-01-01', end_date: '2017-02-01'},
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 1, start_date: '2017-03-01', end_date: '2017-04-01'},
{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 3, start_date: '2017-05-01', end_date: '2017-06-01'}
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work because:

1. You are using `strings`, not `date` objects
2. You are strictly comparing the ranges (`==`), you need to use (`<=` && `>=`)

So, here is a full example, notice the `Date.parse` and `<= >=`:

```
require 'date'

params[:start_date] = '2017-01-01'
params[:end_date] = '2017-06-01'

array.select {|e| Date.parse(e[:start_date]) >= Date.parse(params[:start_date]) && Date.parse(e[:end_date]) <= Date.parse(params[:end_date]) }
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse

**UPDATE** As pointed by [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345486/return-data-from-array-of-hash-based-on-date-range/48345733#comment83684395_48345733) there is no need to do `Date.parse`, but I think it's a good way to validate the string, especially if it's coming from params.

Comment: Thank you so much. really appreciate your help. have a nice day!!

Comment: What's the point of converting the strings to `Date` objects? Why replace `e[:start_date] >= e[:end_date]` with `Date.parse(e[:start_date]) >= Date.parse(params[:start_date])`? Note that the strings are in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) format, so they can be compared as strings.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, for the purpose of the question is not required, but I do think is a good practice to use `Date.parse` because that way you are checking that it's a valid date (otherwise it will throw an error), and not just doing an alphanumeric string comparison, especially if he's getting `start_date` and `end_date` from `params`.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
▶ allowed = Range.new(*[params[:start_date], params[:end_date]].
▷   map(&Date.method(:parse)))
▶ input.select do |h|
▷   [h[:start_date], h[:end_date]].
▷     map(&Date.method(:parse)).all? &allowed.method(:cover?)
▷ end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using strings instead of date objects is not the problem. The problem is that you are selecting elements of the array whose start date is exactly equal to `params[:start_date]` and whose end date is exactly equal to `params[:end_date]`. Because there aren't any of those, you are getting `[]` in response.

There is no reason to parse dates. Ruby is happy to compare the strings, and so long as they are in the format you provided, the result will be correct. But you need to use comparison operators, or better yet, use [`Comparable#between?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F), which is designed for this purpose.

This does the job:

```
def filter_elements(array, start_date, end_date)
  array.select { |row| [row[:start_date], row[:end_date]].all? { |date| date.between?(start_date, end_date) } }
end

>> filter_elements(array, params[:start_date], params[:end_date])
#> [{:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>1, :start_date=>"2017-01-01", :end_date=>"2017-02-01"}, {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1, :start_date=>"2017-03-01", :end_date=>"2017-04-01"}, {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>3, :start_date=>"2017-05-01", :end_date=>"2017-06-01"}]
```